# React. Как центрировать маркер в ymaps3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yandex-maps-api

Добавляю маркер YMapMarker, но маркер не центрируется, а прикрепляется от левого верхнего угла. Есть ли возможность добавить offset у маркера или изменить точку привязки.

Стандартная привязка:

[image: Маркер сейчас]

Как должно быть:

[image]

```
            <YMap
                location={{ center: [37.61556, 55.75222], zoom: 9 }}
                mode="vector"
            >
                <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />
                <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />

                <YMapMarker coordinates={[37.61556, 55.75222]}>
                    <MapPin />
                </YMapMarker>

                <YMapMarker coordinates={[38.61556, 55.75222]}>
                    <MapPin />
                </YMapMarker>
            </YMap>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле эту проблему проще решать с помощью CSS, а не какими-то свойствами в конфигурации, даже если они есть.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Исправил, добавил маркеру transform: translateX(-50%) и transform: translateY(-10%)